# UI/UX Secondary menu with a single entry

Tags: menu, dropdown

I have a question of ux/ui design : is it a good practice to use a dropdown menu in a vertical 3 dots button with only one option in there ? Is there an alternative?

Example :

A page allowing to edit the content of an email, we want to add a secondary action allowing to reset the content of the email (to its default content).
In a card list, for each card add an option to export it in xls.

[image: example]

Comment: The alternative is to have a direct icon to export.

Answer (score 1):

The 'kebab' menu (three dots), Google's Material Design language, is designed to open smaller inline menu items. But my suggestion for your design is if it is only a single item, instead of using the three dots you can use a meaningful icon and show the action label in a tooltip. Which helps the users to relate the action he/she is following.

Also, this helps a frequent user to take action in a single click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a menu there.

Look at a Material.IO guideline about this
https://material.io/components/cards#actions

[image: overflow menu]

Comment: Ok even if there is only one option in the secondary menu ?

Comment: There is no right way to do, 
If you don't want to implement actions buttons, you can put a option in secondary menu

Comment: To add on, I’d suggest using kebab menu if you have the intention to add in other options in future versions of the software. Otherwise you should have one meaningful icon to reduce the number of clicks users take to complete the action.